# Java Spring-AOP Advice not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I am using Spring AOP for validating my request
I have created annotation and on calling advice when that annotation is hit.

Aspect Class :

```
@Aspect
public class BaseValidationAspect {

@Around(value = "execution(@com.pankanis.module.payval.aspect.BaseValidation * *(..))")
    public Response validate(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("Before");
        try {
            response = (Response)joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {

        }
        System.out.println("After");
        return response;

    }
}
```

Annotation Definition :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface BaseValidation {

}
```

Service Class:

```
public class MessageBuilderImpl extends BaseMessageBuilder implements MessageBuilder {
    @BaseValidation    
    public Response<Object> buildMessage(MessageHelper msg, String... args) {
        Response<Object> resp = new Response<Object>();

        //do something

        return resp;
    }
}
```

My Beans Xml Config :

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />


<bean name="baseValidationAspect"
    class="****.BaseValidationAspect">
    //properties
</bean>


<bean id="messageBuilder" class="****.MessageBuilderImpl"
    parent="baseMsgBuilder">
    //properties
</bean>
```

When I use annotation on controller method around advice is getting called.
But on my service method around advice is not getting called.
What is wrong with this code ?